# Application.Quit() won't work on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make the application quit itself when you press the back/return key of a Android phone.

I tried putting this code in the update of a script attached to a gameObject that is present in all my scenes, because of `DontDestroyOnLoad`:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) 
{ 
    Application.Quit(); 
}
```

I just tested something to see if I get inside the if, when playing on my phone. And I get there. `Application.Quit()` is the issue here. I hope someone can help me and explain how I can quit the app in Android.

Thanks! :)

Comment: maybe this could help you : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/560661/how-do-i-get-inputgetkeydownkeycodeescape-to-regis.html  . "I find that on older phones (on Gingerbread), GetKey() doesn't work either- however, Input.GetAxis() does (once I define an axis that uses menu or escape)" -davididev

Comment: 1.Where did you put `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))`? You have to narrow down your problem and determine if `Input.GetKeyDown` is being called at-all on Android or if `Application.Quit();` is the issue.

Comment: @Programmer I narrowed it down and it seems that Application.Quit() is the issue. I can't figure out why because everywhere on the web it says it should work on Android.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear that Application.Quit() is the issue.

Comment: See my answer for other options you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know Application.Quit() does not work in the editor,

Yes, it does not work in the Editor but you can use `UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying` in the Editor but you have to wrap it around the `UNITY_EDITOR` macro. See the example below:

```
void Quit()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
    #else
    Application.Quit();
    #endif
}
```

> I narrowed it down and it seems that Application.Quit() is the issue.
>   I can't figure out why because everywhere on the web it says it should
>   work on Android

The `Application.Quit()` function should work on Android. If it doesn't then that's a bug.

There is another work-around in Unity.

Here are other workarounds:

**1**. Set [`Input.backButtonLeavesApp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-backButtonLeavesApp.html) to `true` in the `Awake` function. It should **automatically** exit the app when the back button is pressed on Android.

```
void Awake()
{
    Input.backButtonLeavesApp = true;
}
```

---

**2**. If that does not work then kill the process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

If this does not work too then file for a bug report through the Editor.

Comment: Killing the process works like a charm. I didn't try backButtonLeavesApp because I want to show a "are you sure" panel before actually quitting. Thank you! :)

Comment: That's makes sense but at-least one of them solved it. Happy coding!

Comment: @Ricardo Frederiks just stumbled over this, but how about setting it to true only after your confirmation dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Application.Quit() should work, at least it does in my apps.

Here's another, android specific, way of quitting your app in a somewhat controlled way (better than just killing the process):

```
AndroidJavaObject activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
activity.Call("finish");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little added note for editor App runtime: ExitPlaymode();

```
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    UnityEditor.EditorApplication.ExitPlaymode();
    #else
    Application.Quit();
    #endif
```

works aswell (with LTS 2019.4.16f)